# Econometrics/Hypothesis Testing Related

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I have a question regarding test statistics.

What does "the distribution of the statistic under the null really mean?" For instance, the standard $t-test$ that we perform, we say that the ratio of the slope coefficient to the standard error is distributed as $t$ with n-1 degress of freedom under the null. What does that mean? In other words, when we reject the null what are we really rejecting?

Comment: There are many threads on CS that takcle this question....

Answer (score 0):

The null refers to the  null-hypothesis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis